# I cannot download dSYM files from App Store Connect and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I need to get dSYM to use Firebase Crashlytics.
When I tried to get it from Xcode, I got this message below

Xcode Message

[image]

Then, I tried to get from App Store Connect. There was no button to download it.

[App Store Connect Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nBMt.png)

[image]

Finally, I got dSYM from Finder, I found dSYM files, and I uploaded it to Firebase.
But it doesn't work, I cannot see crash reports. Probably something is wrong.

I asked Apple support about Xcode and App Store Connect, but they said just ask at developer forum.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have You Check **TARGET->Build Settings->Debug Information Format->**
Here for Both Debug & Release Checked `DWARF with dSYM File`.

Comment: @KetanOdedra Thanks for your comment. Yes, I did. "DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT" is "DWARF with dSYM File".

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. If you run dwarfdump -u <PathToDsym> does the UUID outputted from the command match the one reported as missing?

Comment: @MikeBonnell NO, the UUID don't much.

Comment: Yep, that's the issue then. Apple seems to be providing you with incorrect dSYMs.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, I don't. I understand the problem is UUID, but I don't know how to get the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode go to window > organizer > choose your archive file > right click > show in finder > right click on the xxcarchive file > show package content > and then you can archive the dSYMs folder.